# Change lambda expression return type to Unit navigation bar

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

i am very beginner. sorry if its too easy or im stupid. i want to make bottom navigation menu with material design 3 kotlin. but this error comes. i want to change visibility of scroll view. what is problem?

again, im using this: [m3.material.io](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/implementation/android)

```
NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.main -> {
                likes.visibility = View.GONE
                mainmenu.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            R.id.starred -> {
                mainmenu.visibility = View.GONE
                likes.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add the error too

Answer (score 2):

Going off memory, but I think you missed the word `set`, as in `setOnItemSelectedListener`, and the listener needs to return a Boolean for all cases. You only returned it for the else case. Very unlikely you need to worry about returning false (for fall-through behavior), so I'd just return treu after the when statement.

```
NavigationBarView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when(item.itemId) {
        R.id.main -> {
            likes.visibility = View.GONE
            mainmenu.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        R.id.starred -> {
            mainmenu.visibility = View.GONE
            likes.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        else -> { }
    }
    true
}
```

If you're possibly going to be adding more tabs, I suggest doing your logic like this so it's easier to maintain all the possible cases without having to repeat similar lines of code. The way you're doing it now, you have to write a line of code per tab for each view, and make sure you get the visibility right for each case. You can use the `isVisible` extension property to hide/show views with Boolean logic.

```
NavigationBarView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
    mainmenu.isVisible = item == R.id.main
    likes.isVisible = item == R.id.starred

    true
}
```

Comment: the syntax for visibility is actually correct here. Kotlin usually does not have 'is' based commands. like just in this case, isVisibility is replaced by visibility in kotlin. And I can verify that because I just did that.

Comment: @VaishnavKanhirathingal I didn't say it was incorrect. I was providing a suggestion to use the Jetpack **core-ktx** `isVisible` extension property because it's better for readability. Using `someView.isVisible = x` is easier to read and write than `someView.visibility = if (x) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE`. And in fact, Kotlin *does* use "is" for Boolean properties by convention. `visibility` is converted from an integer Java property so the word "set" is dropped. When Kotlin generates Boolean properties from Java classes, it keeps the word "is".

Comment: that can be confusing for some. but, I think the actual issue is the listener. I had the same issue. apparently and, in my case, the onItemSelected didn't work and the correct way was the setNavigationItemSelectedListener. Mind you, this was for the navigation top-app-bar. but, it stands to reason that might be the case here too since it is a navbar first and foremost.

Comment: It depends which nav bar class they're using.

Comment: @VaishnavKanhirathingal You're right about Kotlin renaming setters and getters, but in this case it's ``View.visibility`` in Java too - it's not a boolean, it's one of three states

Comment: @cactustictacs Kotlin convention [seems to be](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#properties) to use "is" for Boolean properties. It also preserves the word "is" for Java-converted methods. It drops "set" for non-Boolean converted properties. The Java method we're talking about is [setVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVisibility(int)), so it's dropping the word "set" and doesn't replace it with "is" because it's not a Boolean property. I was suggesting the slightly differently named `isVisible` extension Boolean property.

Comment: @cactustictacs I know that. All I am saying is this syntax isn't wrong in this question. I am  currently using the same syntax on a project but, I have used the setNavigationItemSelectedListener  instead and that is working.

Comment: Current syntax will fail even if it is the right set listener method because it doesn’t return a Boolean for all branches of the condition.

Comment: I’m just realizing maybe OP’s code is out of context and could just be a declaration of the interface, in which case the word “set” can be omitted.

Comment: I guess I didn't observe that. But, does OnItemSelectedListener even require a boolean to be returned? I don't think it does.

Comment: I didn't miss set here, Google say this and I did what Google says

Comment: I did this, but doesn't change visibility of scroll view

Comment: If you're not using the word `set`, then you are just declaring an interface implementation. You still have to set it to your view for it to actually be used.

Comment: @VaishnavKanhirathingal It does require a Boolean to be returned: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener#onNavigationItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)

Comment: @Tenfour04 oops yeah you're right - I was just pointing out ``isVisibility`` isn't a thing, but obviously the Kotlin is in my brain now

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of the `onItemSelected`, It should be `setNavigationItemSelectedListener`. I had the same issue with the material top nav bar so, maybe try this out too. Also, try adding log statements and verify if the click statements are working. here's a sample code for reference -

```
binding.navigationViewMainScreen.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            Log.d(TAG, "navigationViewMainScreen working")
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.log_in -> {
                    loginPrompt()
                    true
                }
                R.id.log_out -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        accountDataStore.logOut(requireContext())
                    }
                    true
                }
                R.id.sign_up -> {
                    findNavController()
                        .navigate(
                            MainScreenFragmentDirections.actionMainScreenFragmentToSignUpFragment()
                        )
                    true
                }
                R.id.remove_account -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Account Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        accountDataStore.resetAccounts(requireContext())
                    }
                    true
                }
                R.id.switch_account -> {
                    switchAccountPrompt()
                    true
                }
                R.id.contract_interface -> {
                    if (userLoggedIn) {
                        findNavController()
                            .navigate(
                                MainScreenFragmentDirections
                                    .actionMainScreenFragmentToContractScreenFragment()
                            )
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(), "Log In Necessary To Continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                        loginPrompt()
                    }
                    true
                }
                R.id.about -> {
                    findNavController()
                        .navigate(
                            MainScreenFragmentDirections
                                .actionMainScreenFragmentToAboutFragment()
                        )
                    Log.d(TAG, "about working")
                    true
                }
                R.id.exit -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "exit working")
                    logOutAndExit()
                    true
                }
                else -> {
                    throw IllegalArgumentException("side menu item not registered.")
                }
            }
        }
```

just focus on the content inside. like this one -

```
R.id.log_in -> {
    loginPrompt()
    true
}
```

here we can see an action is performed and it returns true to verify that. Just don't forget the `true` at the ends. that is used to verify an action has been performed after the button was clicked. Hope it helps.

Comment: But Google says OnItemSelectedListener, your solution working but doesn't change visibility of scroll view.

Comment: so, You tried scrollview.visibility = View.GONE ?

Comment: and, how did you verify it was working?

Comment: Doesn't give any error but does nothing, yes I used it

Comment: but did you try writing the log statements I told you? just type `Log.d("testing","nav listener working")` under the listener above the `when` statement similiar to above example. then, open logcat (bottom bar), then build and run the app and click the menu buttons. if the log statement we just wrote appears in the logcat on clicking then, this is the correct method and we can proceed from there.

Comment: not appears at logcat

Comment: that means it's not working. what about in your previous state while using the `OnItemSelectedListener` did the log statements appear then?

Comment: No either. I don't know why but maybe because of material 3 navigation bar? I did [link](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-bar/implementation)